# How to count columns in a react table

Tags: json, reactjs, react-table, column-count

I am trying to count total number of columns having the same data in a table using reactjs.

The data is like this Json Data:

```
{ 
“IT”:”Java”,
   “Position”:” Trainee”,
   “Remarks”:”Good”
},
{ 
“IT”: “.Net”,
  “Position”:”Software Engineer”,
  “Remarks”: “NULL”
},
 { 
“IT”: “Java”,
 “Position”:”Software Engineer”,
 “Remarks:”Average”
},
 {
“IT”:”.NET”,
 “Position”:”Software Engineer”,
 “Remarks”:”Good”
},
 {
“IT”:”Java”,
 “Position”:”Software Engineer”,
 “Remarks”:”Average”
},
 {
“IT”:”.NET”,
 “Position”:”Trainee”,
 “Remarks”:”Good”
}
```

The table needs to be like this:

```
IT      Position       Remarks
2 Java. 1 trainee.     1 Good.           
        2 Software.    2 Average
           Engineer
      
2 .NET  1 Trainee.     1 Good
        2 Software     2 Average
```

The count gives the total number of common fields in the same column and on clicking on the number it displays the common rows data.
Kindly help me what logic I should ise in this

Comment: You have to combine similar json entries via looping through json. Have you tried any approach?

Comment: I am trying to use a single row as a key and then compare it with each entry and combine similar entries in a single array but its not working